# python - encoding carriage returns in console output

Tags: python

I have the following function:

```
def printProgressBar (iteration, total, prefix = '', suffix = '', decimals = 1, length = 100, fill = '█'):
    """
    Call in a loop to create terminal progress bar
    @params:
        iteration   - Required  : current iteration (Int)
        total       - Required  : total iterations (Int)
        prefix      - Optional  : prefix string (Str)
        suffix      - Optional  : suffix string (Str)
        decimals    - cOptional  : positive number of decimals in percent complete (Int)
        length      - Optional  : character length of bar (Int)
        fill        - Optional  : bar fill character (Str)
    """
    percent = ("{0:." + str(decimals) + "f}").format(100 * (iteration / float(total)))
    filledLength = int(length * iteration // total)
    bar = fill * filledLength + '-' * (length - filledLength)
    print('\r%s |%s| %s%% %s' % (prefix, bar, percent, suffix), end = '\r')
    # Print New Line on Complete
    if iteration == total: 
        print()
```

Which gives me the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):---------------------------| 2.0% Complete
  File "script.py", line 75, in <module>
    printProgressBar(count + 1, len(df), prefix = 'Progress:', suffix = 'Complete', length = 50)
  File "script.py", line 36, in printProgressBar
    print('\r%s |%s| %s%% %s' % (prefix, bar, percent, suffix), end = '\r')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2588' in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I believe it's an encoding error... but I have no idea how to approach solving it. Other questions have suggested using .encode(), but in my situation, I'm not sure where I would do that as opposed to string conversion. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: print out the values for `(prefix, bar, percent, suffix)` separately and see if they work, it may be that one of those is what's causing the error

Comment: What environment are you running this in (terminal, IDLE, other IDE)?  The `fill` character is the \u2588 being referred to in the error - apparently your output is going to something that supports ASCII only.

Comment: @jasonharper I'm running this function in unix, is there a difference in how I should print?

Comment: ```fill = '█'``` is whats causing the issue. Try ```'█'.encode('utf-8')```. Using ```str``` to convert from unicode to encoded text / bytes can cause issues.

Comment: @KurtisStreutker Shouldn't I be encoding the final string since I need to do some string manipulation? Doing so however would alter the output, instead of printing the bars it would be printing encoded values

Comment: @ÉvaristeGalois Hmm yea I don't know what the issue is. The code runs fine on my machine

Comment: What are you doing in particular? I'm simply adding `.encode('utf-8')` to `bar` in the last print statemen, and the output is very strange. Looks like this: `Progress: |b'\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88------------------------------------------------'| 4.6% Complete
`

Comment: Oh sorry, I mean the code you posted works fine on my machine